How to optimize (in Python) the compression of TIFF bitmaps before inserting them in a PDF? Photoshop uses Predictor 2
I have written a tool in Python that reads TIFF images in CMYK or monochrome (gray levels) and assembles them into a PDF. It's using a nice module (mPdf.py) from Didier Stevens and the zlib library to compress the bitmaps. It works nicely.
Now the question: I know that if I use /Filter /FlateDecode and manage to incorporate /DecodeParms with Predictor 2, the bitmaps from TIFF images will compress much better. The final PDF would contain, for instance,
/DecodeParms<</BitsPerComponent 8
              /Colors 4
              /Columns 25470
              /Predictor 2>>

I have grasped the code to get the compressed stream should be close to this:
  import zlib
  
  # compress dictionary using dictionary, zlib stream in z
  # bitmap is an uncompressed data from a TIFF image
  d = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  c = zlib.compressobj(zdict=d)
  z = c.compress(bitmap)
  z += c.flush()

However, I am not sure how to choose the data 'd' I have to feed to the compression object before compressing the bitmap.
Don´t even know if Predictor 2 is the best option, nor how to alter it.
I know which images I am going to compress: all of them 8-bit, some monochrome (1 channel), some CMYK with a single channel containing info, some CMYK with different solid areas of a single color, at 10 different values and lots of empty (white) areas (i.e., 0's in all 4 channels)
In other words, I know that in the bitmaps I want to compress there will be different combinations of bytes appearing frequently, but do not know how to transfer this knowledge into the dictionary data.
Also, since I am not concerned about the compression time, which level parameter (0 to 9) is the most recommendable for size and decompression performance?
Thanks,
Ignacio
